# Post numbers in DFS tree of an undirected graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

How could you prove:
An edge (u,v) is part of an **undirected graph G**. If post(u) $<$ post(v) (i.e. the post number of u is smaller than that of v) then it implies that v is an ancestor of u in the DFS tree.  [image: Question]

So far I have understood that it does in fact imply that so I need to prove this. I have thought of doing it by contradiction but not exactly sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! If this exercise comes from an accessible source, please add a url or reference _in the question_. (Yeah, I know it might come from CLRS. But I could be wrong.) Please show how far you have got and where you got stuck and raise _some specific question_ abou it, instead of just asking the community to do some exercise that is, I assume, designed for you to do. All above will motivate and help people help you faster and better.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Thanks a lot for the guidance, that's quite helpful to keep in mind. I have edited my question to include the details that you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You conclusion is correct.

Here is (the sketch of) a proof.

- If pre($u$) < pre($v$), the search must discover and finish $v$ before it finishes $u$, since $v$ is on $u$’s adjacency list. That is, post($v$) < post($u$) and $v$ is in the subtree rooted at $u$.
- If pre($v$) < pre($u$), the search must discover and finish $u$ before it finishes $v$, since $u$ is on $v$’s adjacency list. That is, post($u$) < post($v$) and $u$ is in the subtree rooted at $v$.